# Basic Problem on Direct Products

Tags: group-homomorphism

I am trying to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are groups, $A \times B$ is
isomorphic to $B \times A.$ I have a feeling that I will want to use
the main theorem of direct products, i.e. that if $G N_1N_2...N_n$ is
a group and $F = N_1 \times N_2 \times ... \times N_n,$ then $G$ and
$F.$ So, I know that $A \times B$ is isomorphic to $AB$, and $B \times A$
is isomorphic to $BA,$ but I am not sure if it would be appropriate to
develop a bijective homomorphism between $AB$ and $BA.$ Any suggestions
on this problem?

Comment: You might try using the First Isomorphism Theorem which says: Let $\phi : G \to H$ be a group homomorphism and $K = \text{Kern } \phi$. Then $G/K \cong \text{Im }\phi.$

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence in your post. It doesn't seem to make sense as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are shortcuts using theorems, but the natural bijection between $A\times B$ and $B \times A$ is $$\phi((a,b))=(b,a)$$
 By 'natural' I mean 'following from the observation that the sets $A \times B$ and $B \times A$ are 'the same with just the order of elements swapped'.

You just have to show $\phi$ is a bijection (find an inverse function) and show $\phi((a_1,b_1))\phi((a_2,b_2))=\phi((a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2))$ to demonstrate isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at the mapping from $A \times B$ to $B \times A$ give by $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$.